# How to multiply number using assembler for 8-bit PIC?

Tags: assembly, pic

How can I mupltiply a natural number with a constant (also natural)?

I am fairly new to PIC and assembler and I need just a simple example to understand how it works (say multiplying 5 and 6 or 5 and 3). I am doing some homework and I am only multiplying small number for now so I don't need examples for bigger numbers and how to handle overflowing and similar.

I found online that this can be done in the following example but it doen't seem right to me so I guess I just don't understand it.

```
movlw d'5'

; multiply W register by 6
addwf W, F
addwf W, F
addwf W, F
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is that code a complete example? Is it really a proper [mre]? And are you *sure* about the multiplication with `6`?

Comment: I put here just a part of code where setting the initial value and multiplication takes place. As far as I understood it, this multiplies the number by 6 but it doesn't seem that way to me. It looks like a multiplication by 3. Is that correct?

Comment: I would say multiplication by **`8`**, because you essentially do `W = W + W` three times (assuming the code you *don't* show is doing proper setup).

Comment: It makes sense to me now. So I guess that using addwf W, W three times would be like multiplying by 3, if I understood it correctly. Thank you :)

Comment: No it's not like multiplying with `3`. Each time you add `W` to itself, it's like multiplying with `2`. Doing it two times is like `2 * 2` (i.e. `4` times). You must use a *different* register or memory cell to store the result if you want other multiplications.

Comment: There is no such thing *Natural* when we talk about assemby. The nature of digital world is binary, hence if you take the nature of numbers in computers into account you have to think in binary. You'd better start studying binary multiplication algorithms in advance. By the way the above code does `5 * 8` multiplication since it adds W to itself and saves the result into it. The three `ADDWF` instructions do `1) 5+5=10; 2) 10+10=20; 3) 20+20=40` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with your assembly language, but in general if you want to multiply by a constant it's easiest to think about the problem in terms of factors of powers of 2.

(Forgive me, I don't know the HTML code for math textbook script)

Let's say you want to multiply a number by 320. Something that you'll do commonly for retro hardware with a 320-pixel wide screen.

We can take `320 * x` and factor it into a sum of powers of two (here's a hint: it helps to look at the binary representation of the number you wish to multiply by!)

`320x = 256x + 64x`

While this seems like a more complicated problem for a computer to solve, it's actually not, since most CPU architectures have a "bit shift" operation, which is effectively a very fast "multiply-by-two." Even for computers that *do* have a hardware `mul` operator, the compiler will prefer to write the multiplication in terms of bit-shifts and adds simply to save time. Despite the code taking up more bytes in your program, it's much quicker than an actual `mul`.

If you don't have a dedicated bit shift instruction, simply adding a register to itself will have the same outcome. In the example above you'd need to copy the starting value to another register first, then do the multiplications separately and add them together at the end.

For a simpler example, if you just want to multiply by 10:

```
; 10x = 8x + 2x
```

You can copy your starting value to another register (if you have any) or memory (if you don't.) Then add that value to itself 3 times. Then take the value you backed up earlier, and add it to itself once. Finally, add the two together and you get your result.

Comment: On an 8-bit PIC, multiply by 256 means copying one register to another, to act as the "high half" of the 2-register result.

Comment: I didn't want to assume that PIC had Z80/x86 style registers, but yes, that's the way you'd do it. I tried to make this answer language-agnostic to illustrate the concept.

Comment: If you want to write an agnostic answer, use a multiplier that could make sense for small 8-bit integers, like multiplying by 10: `(x<<1) + (x<<3)`.  Or `((x<<2)+x) << 1` to do it as `*5 *2`.  I don't think (and didn't say) that 8-bit PIC has 8086 style 16-bit registers.  I meant using two fully separate 8-bit registers to hold the halves of a 16-bit integer, like how you'd do 32-bit integers on a 16-bit machine with add/adc or whatever.

Comment: Sorry, my mind goes to 8086-style registers when somebody says "high half" just out of habit.

Comment: https://microchipdeveloper.com/8bit:bl is the baseline 8-bit PIC architecture, apparently one register, `W`, presumably 8 bits.  (And the "file select" register, which I think is for memory banks).  Oh, that's what instructions like `MOVWF` are for: Move W to f.  I'd never looked at a PIC ISA reference before, and its mnemonics were as non-self-explanatory as PowerPC if you don't know the registers.

Comment: My first assembly language was 6502 where you only had 3 registers and only one of them can really do addition. Multiplying the accumulator by 10 would require a memory write (counting push/pop as memory writes, because, you know, they are)